# prove the consequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{P_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ and $\{Q_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be the two sequences of integers. Assume $Q_n\ne0$ , for all $n\ge 1$ and $\{P_n/Q_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ converges to an irrational number, then show that $\{Q_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ tends to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity.

Since $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are integers and $Q_n\ne0$, for all $n\ge1$ , $\{P_n/Q_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is the sequence of rationals and is converges to an irrational number. Is it possible. I'm not getting how to prove. Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the sequence of integers $\{Q_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded. Then the set of values of $Q_n$ is finite which implies that there is a subsequence $\{Q_{n_k}\}_{k\geq 1}$ which is identically constant and equal to say $Q\not=0$. Now get a contradiction by using the fact that $P_{n_k}/Q_{n_k}=P_{n_k}/Q$ converges to an irrational number.

Comment: K it helps me out that the sequence {Qn} is not convergent. But how to show that sequnce {Qn } diverges to +infinity ..it may diverges to -infinity also

Comment: I think that you have to show that $|Q_n|\to \infty$.

Comment: No modulus sign is not there